# What exactly are Moment 3 and Moment 4 in System.Math.MomentSkewKurtosis

Tags: delphi, math, statistics, freepascal

System.Math.MomentSkewKurtosis is declared as

```
procedure MomentSkewKurtosis(const Data: array of Double; var M1, M2, M3, M4, Skew, Kurtosis: Extended);
```

and returns M1, M2, M3, M4, Skew, Kurtosis where

M1 - Arthmetic Mean

M2 - Population Variance

Skew - Skewness

Kurtosis is Kurtosis

but what exactly M3 and M4 stand for.

The documentation in both Delphi Berlin http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Math.MomentSkewKurtosis 
and Free Pascal http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/math/momentskewkurtosis.html is vague.

Comment: Of course, a look in the sources could be a good indication too. <g>

Comment: @LU RD - Thanks!. Can you please convert your comment to an answer so I can close it.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)

Comment: Karl Pearson introduced the use of the third moment about the mean in calculating skewness and the fourth moment about the mean in the calculation of kurtosis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `M3` and `M4` (the 3rd and 4th order moment) as helper variables in order to calculate skew and kurtosis (extracted from sorce):

> MomentSkewKurtosis: Calculates the core factors of statistical analysis: the first four moments plus the coefficients of skewness and kurtosis.
>
> - M1 is the Mean.
> - M2 is the Variance.
> - Skew reflects symmetry of distribution: M3 / (M2**(3/2))
> - Kurtosis reflects flatness of distribution: M4 / Sqr(M2)